# Maven - deploy incrementally

Tags: java, maven, svn, jenkins, artifactory

we are implementing Maven + Jenkins and we are trying some artifact repositories like Artifactory. We now are deploying with svn -*yes, it's awful*- so we have a lot of requirements from our clients that should be done instantly, like "**please add this button to my js form**" so for now is enough commiting JS file and updating that on client deployed Tomcat.

I need to know if there is a way in Maven to install in a server just an incremental part of our deployable files, because the complete *war file* has about 600MB and it is not viable to download all the war file for a little change of two lines in javascript.

Now we can create a new artifact in each commit, but we cannot understand if it will be possible to achieve a continuous delivery that allow us to send a instant fix to a client server.

All the examples that we saw are referred to deployable artifacts, but there isn't a case in which someone use somethind like `mvn install -mySpecificVersion` and only the changed files are downloaded, or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: CI is a very good idea but if you start deploying to your end server only parts than you violate the reproducibility of that process (pipe line) cause you start to do some kind of merging on the end server which means you need to know if your partial deployment will work with the state you have on your end server...Furthermore i would suggest to make a step in between your CI pipeline and the deployment where a process will calculate the differences and than transfers that...but this is not possible with Maven...But it might be possible to think about such things....

Comment: I don't care if the deployment task implements a complete build, but it is not viabe to download 600mb again just for a js change. I suposed that Artifactory or similar has a kind of hash or something to avoid downloading files that are already present in the server.

Comment: The hash is for the whole artifact (war for example) but not for parts which are inside the war file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of thinking in solutions we figured out that the solution is modules in our project, so the dynamism and instant-fix requirement are related to the core or specific little module. This approach will drive us to a reproducible pipe line and a cheap transfer of data.